# Change embed src using javascript

Tags: javascript, embed, src

I'm new to JS and I need some help. I want to make a random quote page. I have all of the quotes saved as .txt files (1.txt, 2.txt...87.txt).  I like the way embed makes the quote look, just kind of plain and type writer-ish.
The end result I am looking for is changing the src in the embed tag to a random quote whenever the Random button is clicked.

Here is what I have:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Random</button>

<embed id="text" src="a.txt" width="500" height="300">

<p id="rand"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 87) + 1);
document.getElementById("text").src = x + ".txt";
document.getElementById("rand").innerHTML = x + ".txt";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The extra *document.getElementById("rand").innerHTML* was just so I could see if the randomization part was working, which it is.

I'm not sure about the *document.getElementById("test").src = x + ".txt";* part.
I though it was to change the src in whatever tag the id was in but it doesn't seem to be working that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I go it. I ended up using an iframe to load them and it works perfectly

```
<body onload="randomQuote()">
<center>
<button onclick="randomQuote()">Random Quote</button>
<p>
<iframe id="text" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms"     src="a.txt" width="300" height="300"></iframe>
<p id="rand"></p>
<script>
function randomQuote() {
var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 87) + 1);
document.getElementById("text").src=x+".txt";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Does not actually answer the question of how to 'Change embed src using javascript'